# Best way to present table where you can override table values

Tags: tables, user-expectation, data-tables

Say you had a table that is pulling pre-filled data. The user has the ability to review this information or override the pre-filled data with something custom. I'm not sure how to best present the "override" option.

**Current Implementation**
The current implementation is pretty odd and I'd like to improve upon it. The user is shown the field title and field value. The current field value is disabled. There is a third option which asks the user if they would like to "Use the default values", which is checked by default. If they uncheck this, the disabled field data becomes enabled and the user can overwrite this value.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqE8gO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This seems like an odd implementation to me. There is a requirement to keep a way to allow the user to reset back to whatever value the server has (erase their custom value).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's an odd implementation.  I would do the following:

1. Always leave the edit box enabled and have it show the current value.  If the user wants to override the value, they just have to click in the edit box and type.
2. Change the Use Default checkbox to a Reset button.  Clicking the button would set the value in the edit box to the default.  (Maybe there's a better word than Reset in your context?)